# Spark DataFrame Schema Nullable Fields

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I wrote the following code in both Scala & Python, however the DataFrame that is returned doesn't appear to apply the non-nullable fields in my schema that I am applying. `italianVotes.csv` is a csv file with '~' as a separator and four fields. I'm using Spark **2.1.0**.

#### italianVotes.csv

```
2657~135~2~2013-11-22 00:00:00.0
2658~142~2~2013-11-22 00:00:00.0
2659~142~1~2013-11-22 00:00:00.0
2660~140~2~2013-11-22 00:00:00.0
2661~140~1~2013-11-22 00:00:00.0
2662~1354~2~2013-11-22 00:00:00.0
2663~1356~2~2013-11-22 00:00:00.0
2664~1353~2~2013-11-22 00:00:00.0
2665~1351~2~2013-11-22 00:00:00.0
2667~1357~2~2013-11-22 00:00:00.0
```

#### Scala

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema =  StructType(
StructField("id", IntegerType, false) ::
StructField("postId", IntegerType, false) ::
StructField("voteType", IntegerType, true) ::
StructField("time", TimestampType, true) :: Nil)

val fileName = "italianVotes.csv"

val italianDF = spark.read.schema(schema).option("sep", "~").csv(fileName)

italianDF.printSchema()

// output
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- postId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- voteType: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- time: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

#### Python

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("postId", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("voteType", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("time", TimestampType(), True),
])

file_name = "italianVotes.csv"

italian_df = spark.read.csv(file_name, schema = schema, sep = "~")

# print schema
italian_df.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- postId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- voteType: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- time: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

My main question is why are the first two fields nullable when I have set them to non-nullable in my schema?

Comment: Interesting to say the least!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In general Spark `Datasets` either inherit `nullable` property from its parents, or infer based on the external data types.

You can argue if it is a good approach or not but ultimately it is sensible. If semantics of a data source doesn't support nullability constraints, then application of a schema cannot either. At the end of the day it is always better to assume that things can be `null`, than fail on the runtime if this the opposite assumption turns out to be incorrect.

Comment: hi how can we know  If semantics of a data source doesn't support nullability constraints

Comment: @rajNishKuMar As a rule of thumb - if something is plain text format, which doesn't provide schema, it doesn't enforce any constraints.

Comment: @zero323 does it mean if I read json and then do printSchema() I'll always get nullable = true for all fields, even if a field is never null as per the data ? My question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61425977/why-spark-outputs-nullable-true-when-schema-inference-left-to-spark-in-case/61426551?noredirect=1#comment108664547_61426551

Comment: Not sure this argument holds water since csv also doesn't have types, yet Spark allows coercion of types by specifying a schema, but not nullability by specifying a schema. IMHO it ought to just throw an exception if the data contains nulls where the schema mandates otherwise.

Comment: I strongly disagree:-/. A sensible way to handle this would be to immediately raise an exception before event touching the underlying file and tell the user, that nullable=False is not supported for the respective data source. 
The alternative would be to validate the data on read, which is probably what was intended by the user in the first place, but which has the downside that it may be quite expensive. However, if as a user i provide nullable=False, i probably want to make that check at some point either way, so I might as well establish all the guarantees on my data when I load it.