# Spark - CSV - Nullable false is NOT throwing exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

Bit confused , why Spark is NOT throwing exception while schema is defined with nullable fase. Here is my example

```
val testCSVPath = "src/main/resources/data/test.csv"   

    val testSchema = StructType(
      Array(
        StructField("name", StringType, false),
        StructField("age", IntegerType, false)))

    val testDFWithSchema =
      sparkSession
        .read
        .format("csv")
        .schema(testSchema)
        .option("header", "true")
        .load(testCSVPath)

    testDFWithSchema.show()
```

CSV file input

```
name,age
"a",1
"b",2
null,3
"c",4
"",5
```

The CSV file name column value is empty . but it is not throwing any exception. Any idea
My spark version 2.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK This is not the behaviour in spark-csv.

as you are expecting null validation like in this example.

```
  val schema = List(
    StructField("name", StringType, false),
    StructField("age", IntegerType, true)
  )

  val data = Seq(
    Row("Hadoop Learner", null),
    Row(null, 21)
  )

  val df = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
    StructType(schema)
 ).show
```

In your  variable `data` second row is `null` and will give  `RuntimeException` `assertnotnull` ...
like below...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: The 0th field 'name' of input row cannot be null.
staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, name), StringType), true, false) AS name#27
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, age), IntegerType) AS age#28
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:593)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:593)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The 0th field 'name' of input row cannot be null.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.StaticInvoke_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:289)
    ... 25 more
[2020-04-13 00:20:18,012] WARN Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: The 0th field 'name' of input row cannot be null.
staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, name), StringType), true, false) AS name#27
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, age), IntegerType) AS age#28
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:593)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:593)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The 0th field 'name' of input row cannot be null.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.StaticInvoke_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:289)
    ... 25 more
 (org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager:66)
[2020-04-13 00:20:18,013] ERROR Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times; aborting job (org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager:70)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: The 0th field 'name' of input row cannot be null.
staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, name), StringType), true, false) AS name#27
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, age), IntegerType) AS age#28
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:593)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:593)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The 0th field 'name' of input row cannot be null.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.StaticInvoke_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:289)
    ... 25 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:751)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:719)
    at examples.CSVTestNPE$.delayedEndpoint$examples$CSVTestNPE$1(CSVTestNPE.scala:58)
    at examples.CSVTestNPE$delayedInit$body.apply(CSVTestNPE.scala:8)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at examples.CSVTestNPE$.main(CSVTestNPE.scala:8)
    at examples.CSVTestNPE.main(CSVTestNPE.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: The 0th field 'name' of input row cannot be null.
staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, name), StringType), true, false) AS name#27
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, age), IntegerType) AS age#28
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:593)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:593)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The 0th field 'name' of input row cannot be null.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.StaticInvoke_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:289)
    ... 25 more
```

But in your example :

```
  val testSchema = StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("name", StringType, false),
      StructField("age", IntegerType, false)))

  val testDFWithSchema =
    spark
      .read
      .format("csv")
      .schema(testSchema)
      .option("header", "true")
 // .option("inferSchema","true")
    .load("./csvsample")
  testDFWithSchema.printSchema()
  testDFWithSchema.show
```

will print

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)

+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
|   a|  1|
|   b|  2|
|null|  3|
|   c|  4|
|null|  5|
+----+---+
```

*if you observe the schema as tree string is saying that `nullable = true` even you set it as `false`.*

#### Conclusion :

I arrived to a conclusion that spark-csv api doesnt not have data source level support for null constraints

Further reading [Spark DataFrame Schema Nullable Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41706862/647053)

Comment: Instead of read from static text, can you please try to read from file path using load

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ram... can you please explain why we need to add null value as third param. .can you please explain?  Learnt new item today..

Comment: seems like this answer is wrong. actually spark csv  nullable false is not supported I guess

Comment: after creation of the data frame and load the data you validate null values seperately.

Comment: Even for JSON also.. did you noticied that one?

Comment: huhaaa... i havent dealt with custom schema for csv or json anyways will make a note of it

Answer (score -1):

You'd have to use `mode` when setting up a read.

```
spark
      .read
      .format("csv")
      .schema(schema)
      .option("mode", "failFast") // default: permissive
      .load("path")
```

Comment: changing the mode to failFast will still result in a schema where nullable=True, even when the specified schema has nullable=False on spark 3.4