# Why Spark outputs nullable = true, when schema inference left to Spark, in case of JSON?

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, jsonschema

Why does Spark show *nullable = true*, when schema is not specified and its inference is left to Spark ?

```
// shows nullable = true for fields which are present in all JSON records.
spark.read.json("s3://s3path").printSchema()
```

Going through the class [JsonInferSchema](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/json/JsonInferSchema.scala#L347), can see that for StructType, explicitly nullable is set to *true*. But am unable to understand the reason behind it.

PS: My aim is to infer schema for a large JSON data set (< 100GB), and wanted to see if Spark provides the ability or would have to write a custom map-reduce job as highlighted in the paper: 
[Schema Inference for Massive JSON Datasets](https://openproceedings.org/2017/conf/edbt/paper-62.pdf). One major part is I want to know which fields are optional and which are mandatory (w.r.t the data set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it may do a sample of the data for schema inference in which it cannot 100% infer if null or not null, due to limited checking scope, sample size. Hence safer to set to null. That simple.

Comment: Could you elaborate a more. As by default sampleRatio is 1.0 : https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ef2d63bfb1859232d166320896957c0543c059cc/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/json/JSONOptions.scala#L50-L51

Not sure if 1.0 means complete data or complete partition though.

Comment: But you can override that

Comment: Sorry  I'm bit confused. Default is 1.0, and I am not overriding it. So if its checking the schema of all records (assuming 1.0 means complete data) then, shouldn't it be able to tell with certainty if a field is nullable or not ?

Comment: As you stated, from the code it is what it is set to. Because when you do not do 100% scan for inference it is safer to set to nullable. They then decided that as most will not sample 100% that the setting should always be so.