# A dataset is loaded from a csv file, with a schema asking fields to be considered as not nullable. Then, a printSchema() describes the fields nullable

Tags: java, apache-spark

I load a csv file with `Apache Spark`.

```java
Dataset<Row> csv = session.read().schema(schema()).format("csv")
  .option("header","true").option("delimiter", ";").load("myFile.csv").selectExpr("*");
```

For it, I provided a schema :

```java
public StructType schema(boolean renamed) {
   StructType schema = new StructType();

   schema = schema.add("CODGEO", StringType, false)
     .add("P16_POP1564", DoubleType, false)
     .add("P16_POP1524", DoubleType, false)
     .add("P16_POP2554", DoubleType, false)
     .add("P16_POP5564", DoubleType, false)
     .add("P16_H1564", DoubleType, false)
      ....
   return schema;
}
```

The dataset is loaded. A `printSchema()` on it displays me this on the console :

```
root
 |-- CODGEO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- P16_POP1564: double (nullable = true)
 |-- P16_POP1524: double (nullable = true)
 |-- P16_POP2554: double (nullable = true)
 |-- P16_POP5564: double (nullable = true)
 |-- P16_H1564: double (nullable = true)
 ...
```

But every field is tagged as *nullable = true*.

And I explicitly asked each of them to be not nullable.

What's the problem ?

Comment: for same question & answered here  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705602/spark-dataframe-schema-nullable-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it is working well-

> **By default, empty string("") is considered as null while reading csv**

### Test-1. Dataset having null & Schema nullable=false

```java
  String data = "id  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4 Col_5\n" +
                "1    A     B      C     D     E\n" +
                "2    X     Y      Z     P     \"\"";

        List<String> list = Arrays.stream(data.split(System.lineSeparator()))
                .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\s+", ","))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<StructField> fields = Arrays.stream("id  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4 Col_5".split("\\s+"))
                .map(s -> new StructField(s, DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read()
                .schema(new StructType(fields.toArray(new StructField[fields.size()])))
                .option("header", true)
                .option("sep", ",")
                .csv(spark.createDataset(list, Encoders.STRING()));
        df1.show();
        df1.printSchema();
```

Output-

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificSafeProjection.createExternalRow_0_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificSafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3384)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
```

Conclusion- Expected behaviour **PASS**

### 2. Dataset having null & Schema nullable=true

```java
  String data = "id  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4 Col_5\n" +
                "1    A     B      C     D     E\n" +
                "2    X     Y      Z     P     \"\"";

        List<String> list = Arrays.stream(data.split(System.lineSeparator()))
                .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\s+", ","))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<StructField> fields = Arrays.stream("id  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4 Col_5".split("\\s+"))
                .map(s -> new StructField(s, DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read()
                .schema(new StructType(fields.toArray(new StructField[fields.size()])))
                .option("header", true)
                .option("sep", ",")
                .csv(spark.createDataset(list, Encoders.STRING()));
        df1.show();
        df1.printSchema();
```

Output-

```java
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| id|Col_1|Col_2|Col_3|Col_4|Col_5|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|    A|    B|    C|    D|    E|
|  2|    X|    Y|    Z|    P| null|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col_2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col_3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col_4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col_5: string (nullable = true)
```

Conclusion- Expected behaviour **PASS**

### 3. Dataset without null & Schema nullable=true

```java
  String data1 = "id  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4 Col_5\n" +
                "1    A     B      C     D     E\n" +
                "2    X     Y      Z     P     F";

        List<String> list1 = Arrays.stream(data1.split(System.lineSeparator()))
                .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\s+", ","))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<StructField> fields1 = Arrays.stream("id  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4 Col_5".split("\\s+"))
                .map(s -> new StructField(s, DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.read()
                .schema(new StructType(fields1.toArray(new StructField[fields.size()])))
                .option("header", true)
                .option("sep", ",")
                .csv(spark.createDataset(list1, Encoders.STRING()));
        df2.show();
        df2.printSchema();
```

Output-

```java
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| id|Col_1|Col_2|Col_3|Col_4|Col_5|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|    A|    B|    C|    D|    E|
|  2|    X|    Y|    Z|    P|    F|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col_2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col_3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col_4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col_5: string (nullable = true)
```

Conclusion- Expected behaviour **PASS**

Comment: I'm expecting a `printSchema()` that replies to me : `id: string (nullable = false)`

Comment: Its testcase 1, since the data is having null, its failing. You can have 4th test, dataset without null and nullable=false

Comment: Why is your output telling your fields are `nullable = true` if they are not ? Why `printSchema()` doesn't writes "... : string (nullable = false)" if the field are not nullable. This is my question.